# write a spark dataframe or write a glue dynamic frame, which option is better in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

In AWS Glue, I read the data from data catalog in a glue dynamic frame. Then convert the dynamic frame to spark dataframe to apply schema transformations. To write the data back to s3 I have seen developers convert the dataframe back to dynamicframe. Is there any advantage over writing a glue dynamic frame to writing a spark dataframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find that there is functionality that is available only to dynamic frame writer class that cannot be accessed when using data frames:

1. Writing to a [catalog table based](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-writer.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-writer-from_catalog) on an s3 source as well when you want to utilize connection to JDBC sources. i.e using [`from_jdbc_conf`](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-writer.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-writer-from_jdbc_conf)
2. Writing to parquet using format [`glueparquet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-format-glue-parquet) as a format.
3. Tracking processed files in the target location using [bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html)

These are some of the use-cases I can think of, but if you have a use case that requires using save modes, for example, `mode('overwrite')` you could use data frames. A similar approach however exists at dynamic frame but is implemented slightly different. You can take a look at `[purge_s3_path][3]` then write.

Comment: Is there any advantage over writing a glue dynamic frame to writing a spark dataframe?

Comment: Is there performance benefits in using one over the other?